# Background image Z-index

Tags: html, css, angularjs, z-index

I have an accordion menu that slides down over another container that has a background image.  When the menu is opened it pushes the background image down the page.  I've tried playing around with z-index and also changing the containers background url to an img tag on the html file, but still no luck.  Any advice?

```
<!--Dropdown menu on mobile-->
<div ng-hide="burgerChangeToX" class="nav_dropdown_mobile">
  <a ui-sref-active="selected" ui-sref="home">Home</a>
  <a ui-sref-active="selected" ui-sref="about">About</a>
  <a ui-sref-active="selected" ui-sref="skills">Skills</a>
  <a  ui-sref-active="selected"ui-sref="work">Work</a>
  <a ui-sref-active="selected" ui-sref="fun">Fun</a>
</div>

<!-- background image -->
<div class="background_container">
  <div class="background_mobile"></div>
</div>

/*Mobile navbar dropdown*/
.nav_dropdown_mobile {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    transition: margin-top .75s ease;
    font-family: Yantramanav;
    z-index: 5;
}

/* container with background image */
.background_mobile {
    background: url('../img/Wolf_blue.svg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 90%;
    height: 58vh;
    margin-top: 50px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Provide us your HTML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for You to place your menu on top of the `<div class="background_container"></div>` , you must give the `<div ng-hide="burgerChangeToX" class="nav_dropdown_mobile"></div>`  a position property of `position: absolute;`. Also, give the background container div a position of relative so it can relatively position itself in regard to the positioning of other elements.

> When you set an element to be positioned asbolutely, it is being removed from the flow of the document, placing itself above everything else. Therefore it will be on top of the background-image container div.

This way your z-index should work just fine. You might have to do some margin/padding trickery in order for your layout to remain the same.

> You can find more thorough explanation here at the **[Mozilla Developer Network (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)**

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative` in your CSS code, z-index need postion

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that did not work.  That, and I believe the containers have position: relative by default in this example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand and what you want is that the menu passes over the image, you have to give absolute position to `.nav_dropdown_mobile`

Answer (score 0):

Give `.nav_dropdown_mobile` the `position` of `absolute` so it takes up no space and then position it to the `top:0px;`.

Here is the code:

```
.nav_dropdown_mobile {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    transition: margin-top .75s ease;
    font-family: Yantramanav;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7zr0x6b1/)

Answer (score 0):

Adding a position: Absolute to the dropdown container did the trick.  Thanks for all the replies.